# How do I fix TortoiseSVN displaying random icon overlays?

Tags: icons, tortoise-svn

I use TortoiseSVN (latest version) and sometimes all the icon overlays it uses get randomized with quite peculiar results. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the TortoiseSVN FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#ovlmessed):

> Why do the overlay icons sometimes change to random graphics?
>
> The Windows icon cache is a fairly buggy creature. You can solve this in one of the following ways:
>
> - Install Microsoft's [TweakUI](http://www.microsoft.com/ntworkstation/downloads/powertoys/networking/nttweakui.asp) and run the option to rebuild icons.
> - Or increase the icon cache size. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows>\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer` and add a new String Value called `Max Cached Icons`. The default value is `500` - try increasing it to `2048` (see [Q132668](http://support.microsoft.com/support/kb/articles/Q132/6/68.asp) in the Microsoft knowledge base for more details).
> - Or delete the file called ShellIconCache in your Windows directory. And reboot.
> - With TortoiseSVN 1.3.0 and later, you can also rebuild the icon cache by calling TortoiseProc from the command line like this `TortoiseProc.exe /command:rebuildiconcache`

Answer (score 3):

Found [a solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q132668/):

> Using Registry Editor, add a `Max Cached Icons` string value with a value data of 2000 to the following registry key, and then restart your computer:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

Comment: I suggest that you delete this answer, and put this info in the post itself. It's just too weird having the poster also giving answers.

Comment: Really? But that's what the official guidelines say to do! Even if the OP is the one who gives the answer, it should appear in an answer post. But maybe I'm confused.

Comment: @scraimer You're entirely correct, for three reasons: if the answer is embedded in the question, the resolution is easily overlooked, the question cannot have an accepted answer and from a list view, it doesn't appear as having any (accepted) answer(s).